# If $f$ is an entire function such that $f(iy) = \exp(iy)$ where $0 \leq y \leq 1$. Is $f(x+iy) = \exp(x+iy)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$(1)$ If $f$ is an entire function such that $f(iy) = \exp(iy)$ where $0 \leq y \leq 1$. Then, is $f(x+iy) = \exp(x+iy)$ for every $x$ and every $y$?

$(2)$ If $f$ is an entire function such that $f(iy) = iy$ where $0 \leq y \leq 1$. Then:

$\qquad (a)$ $f(z) = y$ for every $x$ and every $y$

$\qquad (b)$ $f(z) = z$ for every $x$ and for every $y$

$\qquad(c)$ $f(z) = z$ only for $0 \leq y \leq 1$

$\qquad (d)$ $f(z) = z$ whenever $0 \leq y \leq 1$

My thoughts:

I think analytic continuation will play a part here. So, this is how I visualise this: If we draw a circular neighborhood at $z = i$ then, since $f$ is analytic, it must display same limit behavior everywhere in that neighborhood. So, $f(z) = e^z$ everywhere?

Regarding the second question too, I think the same, $f(z) = z$ everywhere?

However, I know that my argument is not concrete enough. Could you tell me a more definite and concrete way to tackle this kind of problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of the identity theorem for holomorphic functions: If $f,g$ are holomorphic on $D$ and agree on infinitely many points (here, the line segment $\{iy\mid 0\le i\le 1\}$ ) and these points have an accumulation point in $D$, then $f=g$.

Comment: von Etizen So, that means f(z) = e<sup>z</sup> everywhere in first case and f(z) = z everywhere in second case right ? The answer in the second case in my textbook says f(z) = z only in the given interval when y is in [0 , 1] which must be wrong right ?

Comment: $f(z)=z$ for all $z$ is right. Does the textbook agree that $f(z)=e^z$ for all $z$ in the first question? Note that any non-identity fucntion for (2) could easily be transformed to a non-exp function for (1), which would mean the authors contradict themselves ...

Comment: Yeah, it agrees that f(z) = e^z .